# Alternative ways too body onload to call this specific function

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have an auto refresh script here, it works beautifully, but calling LoadPage via body onload blocks several other scripts on my pages. I've tried calling it through many other suggested alternatives to body onload, but nothing so far works. Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script>  
      var asdf = false;  
      function StartTime(){  
        if(asdf)clearTimeout(asdf)  
        asdf = setTimeout("RefreshPage()",15000);  
      }  
      function RefreshPage(){  
clearTimeout(asdf)  
        if(document.autorl.RFCB.checked)  
          document.location.href = document.location.pathname + '?Checked'


      }  
      function LoadPage(){  
        var findCheck = document.location.href.split("?Chec");  
        if(findCheck.length == 2){  
          document.autorl.RFCB.checked=true;  
    window.location='#bottom'     
          StartTime()       
        }
      }  
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="LoadPage()">

<div>
<form name="autorl">
Auto-Refresh: <input type="checkbox" name="RFCB" onclick="StartTime()">
</form></div>

<a name="bottom">
```

Could anybody here lend a hand with this?

Comment: asdf. what a name for a variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use something like the document.ready() handler in jQuery to accomplish this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadPage();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Yes this works, it still breaks one script but it's incosiquential, I can use this. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's breaking as a result of a conflict, you can run jQuery in non conflict mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

This will mean using "jQuery" instead of "$"

Answer (score 0):

you can try and call the function from the end of html file just before the `</html>` tag add a `<script>LoadPage();</script>`

Comment: This was a method I had tried, it wasn't successful, thanks though!